# Adding vertical lines in a sidewaystable

Tags: tables, multirow, rotating, nicematrix, sidewaystable

I would like to add vertical lines for certain columns starting from `\midrule` to `\bottomrule` as depicted in the figure provided below.

[image]

I am also providing a MWE. I tried to use `*{3}{c}| *{2}{r r r}}`, however it does not generate the exact output that I want (the undesired output is shown below).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

  \begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\bfseries\linespread{1}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
  \centering
  \caption{My Table}{
 \small
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                        *{3}{c}
                        *{2}{r r r}}
                        
     \toprule
    &  &   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{First}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ Second}   \\
    \cmidrule(l){4-6} \cmidrule(l){7-9}
    {A} & {B}  & {C} 
    & {\makecell{D}} & {\makecell{E}} & {\makecell{F}}  & {\makecell{X}} & {\makecell{Y}} & {\makecell{Z}}  \\
    \midrule
    
 1 & 2 & 3 &4 & 5& 6 &7 & 8& 9  \\
 11 & 12 & 13 &14 & 15& 16 &17 & 18& 19  \\
  21 & 22 & 23 &24 & 25& 26 &27 & 28& 29  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
}
   \end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use left-trimming, and your tableau will be just fine *without* the vertical lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I am required to add those lines to make a point in my paper. This is just a minimal example. In essence, adding the vertical lines to my own table is important.

Comment: Horizontal lines from the bokksabt package are incompatible with vertical lines.

Comment: I must confess I don't understand why you use a `tabular*` environment instead of, say, a `tabularx` environment. Whenever `\extracolsep{\fill}}` in force, `tabular*` environments wtth vertical rules simply look awful, whether or not the line-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package are used. What's your reason for using `tabular*`?

Comment: @Mico I've never used ```tabularx``` environment before. Since I`ve created my tables with ```tabular*``` in the past, I just went with it.

Comment: @leandriis Then, it does not make sense to try anything on my current example, right? I should probably consider a different approach?

Comment: I currently have a hard time understanding the choice for `sidewaystable` and `tabular*` for this particular table since, at least in its current form, it should easily fit onto a portrait page. Since `tabular*` definitely is part of the problem here, it might be better to not use it for this particular table, especially if you insist on vertical lines. From the sketch in your question, I guess, you're interested in table 1 in the following screenshot, but wouldn't table 2 also be sufficient to visually separate your blocks of columns from each other? https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2k1o.png

Comment: @leandriis Since this is an MWE, it might not make sense to use ```sidewaystable```, but in my real example, I have over 20 columns and I am trying to make a distinction between different data points.

Comment: @ball_jan: Thanks for the clarification. What about the two example outputs in my previous comment?

Comment: @leandriis The first figure is exactly what I want on a ```sidewaystable```.

Comment: @leandriis I meant in your comment at  i.stack.imgur.com/s2k1o.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

That vertical rules are not interrupted by rules defined in `booktabs` package  you should replace `\toprule`, `\bottomrule` and `\midrule` for example with `Xhline{<width>}` .

In MWE below are used `S` columns for better number align. With use of the `tabularx` table are prescribed columns width:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{C}{#2}}

%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % new

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[hp]
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \sisetup{table-format=2, 
             table-column-width=4em}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \centering
\caption{My Table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{3}{S}| *{3}{S}| *{3}{S} }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\mcc[3]{}           & \mcc[3]{First}& \mcc[3]{Second}       \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-6}  \cmidrule(l){7-9}
\mcx{A} & \mcx{B}   & \mcx{C}   & \mcx{D}   & \mcx{E}   & \mcx{F}   & \mcx{X}   & \mcx {Y}  & \mcx{Z}   \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
 1      &  2        &  3        &  4        &  5        &  6        &  7        &  8        &  9        \\
11      & 12        & 13        & 14        & 15        & 16        & 17        & 18        & 19        \\
21      & 22        & 23        & 24        & 25        & 26        & 27        & 28        & 29        \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I illustrated what I want in the first figure in my post. For instance, the horizontal line in your example starts from the top of the table. I want it to go from the middle to the bottom. In addition, I would like to place a similar line between F and X.

Comment: @ball_jan, now is clear. You like to reproduce first image, not the second. I will correct this ASAP.

Comment: Thank you! I also edited my post accordingly since I see your point about why it could confuse others.

Comment: @ball_jan, see edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to reproduce your MWE using the `nicematrix` package. It creates TikZ nodes so it is possible to draw the vertical lines you need, with two tikz commands.

The package offers the command `\Block` that is able to create multicolumn / multirow cells.

`\Block{1-3}{First}` creates a  1 row x 3 columns cell with a centered `First` inside.

Aware that this is super simplified MWE I added another, more complete example, using `\Block`.

`\Block{}{<content>}` creates a 1 row x 1 column cell that allows to use `\\` inside.

Assuming the second lines of headings could have longer text than A, B, C, ... and some of them might need to be split into two or more lines, all those headings were included in a `\Block` command, that also centered them.

Due to the tikz nodes two compilations might be needed the first time.

[image: ar]

[image: br]

This is the code. As you can see very compact and easy to maintain.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\centering
  \caption{My Table I}
  \medskip
\small

\begin{NiceTabular}{!{\extracolsep{4pt}}*{3}{c} *{2}{r r r}}[%
    cell-space-limits=5pt, %expand cells vertically
    columns-width = 1.8cm, %adjust as needed
    ]   
    \hline
    &   &   &\Block{1-3}{First} &   &   & \Block{1-3}{Second}   &   &   \\
    \cline{4-6} \cline{7-9}
    A   &B  &C  &
    \bfseries D &
    \bfseries E &
    \bfseries F &
    \bfseries X &
    \bfseries Y &
    \bfseries Z \\
    \hline
1   &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9  \\
11  &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 &17 &18 &19 \\
21  &22 &23 &24 &25 &26 &27 &28 &29 \\
\hline
\CodeAfter
{%
    \tikz \draw (row-3-|col-4) -- (row-6-|col-4);
    \tikz \draw (row-3-|col-7) -- (row-6-|col-7);
}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{sidewaystable}


\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{My Table II}
    \medskip
    \small
\begin{NiceTabular}{!{\extracolsep{4pt}}*{3}{c} *{2}{r r r}}[%
    cell-space-limits=5pt, %expand cells vertically
    columns-width = 1.8cm, %adjust as needed
    ]   
    \hline
    &   &   &\Block{1-3}{First} &   &   & \Block{1-3}{Second}   &   &   \\
    \cline{4-6} \cline{7-9}
    \Block{}{A }    &
    \Block{}{B \\ line} &
    \Block{}{C \\ line} &
    \Block[c]{}<\bfseries>{D \\ line}   &
    \Block[c]{}<\bfseries>{E }  &
    \Block[c]{}<\bfseries>{F \\ line}   &
    \Block[c]{}<\bfseries>{X \\ line}   &
    \Block[c]{}<\bfseries>{Y \\ line}   &
    \Block{}<\bfseries>{Z}                 \\
    \hline
    1   &2  &3  &4  &5  &6  &7  &8  &9  \\
    11  &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 &17 &18 &19 \\
    21  &22 &23 &24 &25 &26 &27 &28 &29 \\
    \hline
    \CodeAfter
    {%
        \tikz \draw (row-3-|col-4) -- (row-6-|col-4);
        \tikz \draw (row-3-|col-7) -- (row-6-|col-7);
    }
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```